# Redux Saga stopped by LOCATION_CHANGE too early

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux, redux-saga

So I'm injecting Sagas dynamically when the route loads

```
  path: '/home',
  name: 'home',
  getComponent(nextState, cb) {
    require.ensure([],
      require => {
        let HomePageReducer = require('./containers/HomePage/reducer').default;
        let HomePageSagas = require('./containers/HomePage/sagas').default;
        let HomePage = require('./containers/HomePage').default;

        injectReducer('home', HomePageReducer);
        injectSagas(HomePageSagas);

        cb(null, HomePage);
      })
  },
```

`injectAsyncSagas` goes like this:

```
export function injectAsyncSagas(store) {
  return (sagas) => sagas.map(store.runSaga);
}
```

where `store.runSaga` is `sagaMiddleware.run`, created during store creation.

When the route loads the saga is successfully started. It's listening for actions.

```
export function* mySagaFunction() {
    console.log("Start mySagaFunction");
    while (true) {
    const watcher = yield race({
      loadRepos: take(SOME_HOME_PAGE_ACTION),
      stop: take(LOCATION_CHANGE), // stop watching if user leaves page
    });

    if (watcher.stop) {
      console.log("Stop mySagaFunction", watcher.stop);
      break;
    }
    //other statements here to handle SOME_HOME_PAGE_ACTION
}
```

When I load the route, "Start mySagaFunction" is consoled. If I dispatch SOME_HOME_PAGE_ACTION, it successfully does whatever it has to do.
When I leave the page, react router calls LOCATION_CHANGE, and Saga consoles "Stop mySagaFunction" implying it successfully quit the while loop.

Then I go to another route and come back to this route.
This time LOCATION_CHANGE is dispatched by router, as expected. But Saga is starting and then stopping immediately. My console goes like this:

```
Start mySagaFunction
Stop mySagaFunction
```

In Redux dev tools I see only one LOCATION_CHANGE. How do I figure out why the Saga is starting and immediately stopping? It happens only if I come back to the route.

I thought maybe LOCATION_CHANGE was being dispatched late. But no. In my reducers I consoled the action type. Reducer is called first with LOCATION_CHANGE and saga starts and then saga stops.

I'm using `Link` to navigate between pages. I tried `browserHistory.push(url)` and `dispatch(push(url))` as well. Same result.

Note: I got the code for injecting the sagas from [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate). I have only taken this code and I'm not using the boilerplate itself. I ran the boilerplate and this bug is not happening there. Differences are:

- It's using `selectLocationState` in syncHistoryWithStore. My whole store is not Immutable so I don't need that.
- It's using it's own `routeReducer` instead of `routerReducer` from `react-router-redux`. I don't know why, maybe because of full immutable store.

Anyways in the boiler plate code I removed the above two points and still the scenario is not occurring.

Comment: Have you ever gotten to solving this issue?

Comment: @AndreyCizov yeah, posted an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The route had an onEnter redirect and hence LOCATION_CHANGE would be dispatched twice thereby cancelling the saga.

```
{
    path: 'home',
    getComponent(nextState, cb) {
        require.ensure([], require => {...})
    },
    indexRoute: {
            onEnter: (nextState, replace) => replace('/home/A')
    }
}
```

Workaround for this:

I'm dispatching a LEAVE_PAGE action in onLeave hook for every page that injects sagas

```
onLeave: ()=> {
          store.dispatch({type: LEAVE_HOME_PAGE});
        }
```

and in the saga watch for that particular action:

```
const watcher = yield race({
  loadRepos: take(SOME_HOME_PAGE_ACTION),
  stop: take(LEAVE_HOME_PAGE), // stop watching if user leaves page
});
```

Comment: This is what I came up with. Any other better solution is appreciated.

Comment: I've had an issue with the saga receiving it's own LOCATION_CHANGE event (the saga being called as a result of dispatch from onEnter). Although my solution was the same. Thanks a lot for the fast answer.