# Saga always cancelled

Tags: redux-saga

I use redux-saga and have the following code:

```
function* loginFlow(username, password) {
  try {
    yield call(loginApi, username, password);
    yield put({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS });
    yield put({ type: TOGGLE_LOGGED_DONE, payload: true });
    yield put(push('/dashboard'));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: LOGIN_ERROR, error });
  } finally {
    if (yield cancelled()) {
      console.log('ALWAYS CANCELLED');
      // yield put(replace('/login'));
    }
  }
}

// Watcher saga.
function* loginWatcher() {
  while (true) {
    const { username, password } = yield take(LOGIN_REQUESTING);
    const task = yield fork(loginFlow, username, password);
    const action = yield take([LOGOUT, LOGIN_ERROR]);
    if (action.type === LOGOUT) yield cancel(task);
    yield call(logoutUser);
  }
}
```

The problem is that the `loginFlow` function always get cancelled in the end (I see `'ALWAYS CANCELLED'` in console). Even if I remove `const action = yield take([LOGOUT, LOGIN_ERROR]);` and `yield call(logoutUser);` from `loginWatcher`.

I can't see that either `LOGOUT` or `LOGIN_ERROR` are fired:
[image: Redux devtools output]

Any ideas what wrong with my code?

Note that I use `withRouter` in the index.js for login page where saga above is (else I get blank screen when redirect):

```
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'login', saga }); 

export default compose( withReducer, withSaga, withConnect, )(LoginPage);
```

Best Regards

EDIT:
If wrapping `loginWatcher` in `try/catch` I also go to `finally` there:

```
function* loginWatcher() {
  while (true) {
    try {
      const { username, password } = yield take(LOGIN_REQUESTING);
      const task = yield fork(loginFlow, username, password);
      const action = yield take([LOGOUT, LOGIN_ERROR]);
      if (action.type === LOGOUT) yield cancel(task);
      yield call(logoutUser);
    } catch (error) {
      yield put({ type: LOGIN_ERROR, error });
    } finally {
      if (yield cancelled()) {
        console.log('HERE AS WELL');
        // yield put(push('/login'));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wrap `loginWatcher()` in a `try { ... } finally { if (yield cancelled()) { ... } }`. I suspect it gets cancelled too.

Comment: @AndreyMoiseev Did you mean like my edit? Go to finally there as well with try/catch...

Comment: @AndreyMoiseev Seems to be something with `yield cancelled()`, it's always true...

Comment: In redux-saga, all `fork`ed and `call`ed sagas are cancelled recursively. Something in your code is cancelling `loginWatcher()`, which in its turn recursively cancels `loginFlow()`.

I suspect two things: 1) the code where you start `loginWatcher()` cancels it, 2) `yield put(push('/dashboard'))` cases a side effect somewhere in your code, and cancels it.

Comment: Please add the code where you start `loginWatcher()`, *and* the code where you handle `LOCATION_CHANGE`. Also, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638549/redux-saga-stopped-by-location-change-too-early). Probably you have code that cancels sagas on `LOCATION_CHANGE`.

Comment: @AndreyMoiseev Aaah! `yield put(push('/dashboard'))` seem to actually cancel. Commenting it out results in no jump to `finally`. I will check.

Comment: @AndreyMoiseev I do like this: const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'login', saga });

export default compose(
  withReducer,
  withSaga,
  withConnect,
)(LoginPage);

Comment: @AndreyMoiseev Do you have some solution how to not get my saga cancelled? Pls post an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm posting what we've gathered as an answer, so that this question is useful for future readers.*

In redux-saga, sagas started via `call()` and `fork()` are cancelled recursively. *Saga* means a recursively cancellable task. So when a saga gets cancelled, you should check its parent saga, and so on.

This code snippet you've posted:

```
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'login', saga });
export default compose( withReducer, withSaga, withConnect, )(LoginPage)
```

Google suggests that it uses [this redux-saga + react-boilerplate example](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/docs/js/redux-saga.md). It covers cancellation and how to disable it. Check the link to find out about it.

I'm not familiar with react-boilerplate (React ecosystem is huge), but I guess my answer at least narrows down the search. Consider asking a separate question with [react-boilerplate](/questions/tagged/react-boilerplate) if you get confused.

Comment: Thank you! What works is to move saga to global scope. Then it is not cancelled during route change!